# Groovy - group and sort list

Tags: groovy

My orginal list is:

```
[[string: firstString, id: 2], 
[string: secondString, id: 1], 
[string: secondString, id: 3], 
[string: firstString, id: 1], 
[string: firstString, id: 3], 
[string: secondString, id: 2]]
```

I want to group it by string and sort it by id just like this:

```
[[string: firstString, id: 1], 
[string: firstString, id: 2], 
[string: firstString, id: 3], 
[string: secondString, id: 1], 
[string: secondString, id: 2], 
[string: secondString, id: 3]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def firstString = 'first'

def secondString = 'second'

def source =
[[string: firstString, id: 2], 
[string: secondString, id: 1], 
[string: secondString, id: 3], 
[string: firstString, id: 1], 
[string: firstString, id: 3], 
[string: secondString, id: 2]]
```

**Your stated expected result:**

```
def expected =
[[string: firstString, id: 1], 
[string: firstString, id: 2], 
[string: firstString, id: 3], 
[string: secondString, id: 1], 
[string: secondString, id: 2], 
[string: secondString, id: 3]]

def result = source.sort { [it.string, it.id] }
assert result == expected
```

**IDs reversly ordered:**

```
def expected =
[[string: firstString, id: 3], 
[string: firstString, id: 2], 
[string: firstString, id: 1], 
[string: secondString, id: 3], 
[string: secondString, id: 2], 
[string: secondString, id: 1]]

def result = source.sort { [it.string, -it.id] }
assert result == expected
```

**Really grouped, not only sorted by string:**

```
def expected =
[(firstString):
  [[string: firstString, id: 1], 
  [string: firstString, id: 2], 
  [string: firstString, id: 3]], 
(secondString):
  [[string: secondString, id: 1], 
  [string: secondString, id: 2], 
  [string: secondString, id: 3]]]

def result = source.groupBy { it.string }
result.each { it.value.sort { it.id } }
assert result == expected
```

**Really grouped, not only sorted by string, IDs reversely ordered:**

```
def expected =
[(firstString):
  [[string: firstString, id: 3], 
  [string: firstString, id: 2], 
  [string: firstString, id: 1]], 
(secondString):
  [[string: secondString, id: 3], 
  [string: secondString, id: 2], 
  [string: secondString, id: 1]]]

def result = source.groupBy { it.string }
result.each { it.value = it.value.sort { it.id }.reverse() }
assert result == expected
```

**Really grouped and IDs flattened out:**

```
def expected = 
[(firstString): [1, 2, 3], 
(secondString): [1, 2, 3]]

def result = source.groupBy { it.string }
result.each { it.value = it.value.collect { it.id }.sort() }
assert result == expected
```

**Really grouped and IDs flattened out, IDs reversely ordered:**

```
def expected = 
[(firstString): [3, 2, 1], 
(secondString): [3, 2, 1]]

def result = source.groupBy { it.string }
result.each { it.value = it.value.collect { it.id }.sort().reverse() }
assert result == expected
```